# AWS EC2 taking snapshot or LVM of only folder

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot, lvm

I am working on AWS ec2 instance. I have configured MongoDb on it.

```
 1. I have 1TB storage space for mongo data to be store. 
 2. Other 50 GB for application to run.
```

Since cost of taking snapshot of everything is huge, Can I take snapshot of only folder where my mongodb data is stored.

```
  e.g my folder for mongodb storage is /home/ubuntu/mongodb
```

So I want snap shot or LVM of only mongodb folder instead of taking it for 1 TB instance on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

you can take dumps of your database.

```
mongodump --dbpath /data/db/ --out /data/backup/
or
mongodump --host mongodb.example.net --port 27017
```

and then store it on s3. You can also run cron job for this to take backup of your data at desired time frequency.

Comment: mongodump do not work properly with large data. My question is strictly based on snapshot or LVM on AWS EC2 instance not anything else.

Comment: then you can run lvm for backup if cost is your concern.

Comment: If some-one else face the same issue. Please read this too http://serverfault.com/questions/366337/amazon-ec2-backup-strategy-with-restrictions-little-to-no-snapshots-can-be-take    and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumes.html